# mouseWheelEvent.preventDefault. How to prevent scrolling in browser when swf has focus

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

suppose a small app which connects to server and displays some data. The problem is that when MOUSE_WHEEL is thrown the page is scrolling. How is it possible to disable page scrolling on MOUSE_WHEEL **from flash**? Please do not advice solution on JS side, users place our ccin their blogs/cites so we cannot force them to add any JS.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to block it with pure AS3.  Your only option is to inject JS into the document via `ExternalInterface`.  This won't require your users to add anything to their page beyond the SWF embed code; it just requires your embed code to include `allowScriptAccess` as `sameDomain` or `all`.  Here's an example utility that enables this:

http://www.spikything.com/blog/index.php/2009/11/27/stop-simultaneous-flash-browser-scrolling/

Answer (score 1):

Here, I created a small lib which works on all kind of flash plugins (including chrome Pepper flash) and MAC-OS

It consists of one AS3 file and you won't need to add anything to your site (html) directory

[GIThub Repo](https://github.com/KumoKairo/BlastedMouseWheelBlock)